# check variable is numerical django template

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi I want to check if my variable is numeric in Django template
and I tried this code

```
{% if isnumeric(item) %}
<h1>{{item}}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

but this throws me this error

> Could not parse the remainder: '(item)' from 'isnumeric(item)'

I tried to find a builtin template tag or filter in this page
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/ of Django document

and I searched for this question in StackOverflow too
but I did not found anything related

Comment: What exactly is `item`? A string?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it may string or float or list or anything else, I want to check that is a number or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's a built in template function to check for that. One way to do it is to write your own:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

The code would look something like:

`my_filters.py`

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter()
def is_numberic(value):
    return value.isdigit()
```

And in the html:

```
{% load my_filters %}

{% if item|is_numeric %}
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

isnumeric() python fuction doesn't take any parameters

Make a fuction in your model:

```
def isnumeric(self):
    item = self.item
    if item.isnumeric() is True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

then in your template:

```
{% if item.isnumeric %}
<h1>{{item}}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

With this, you can use the isnumeric() function in your template. You can add an else statement too.

Take a look to [isnumeric() function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isnumeric)